# Making balanced columns that don't reflow when elements change size

Tags: css, css-float, multiple-columns, flexbox

I have a list of things that I want to display in columns. Each thing has a description that is hidden by default, but which expands and displays when you click the list item:

```
<ul>
  <li>First item <div>Here is the description of the first item. This description is extra-super-long so you can see the undesirable reflow behavior in non-flexbox methods.</div></li>
  <li>Second item <div>Here is the description of the second item.</div></li>
  <li>Third item <div>Here is the description of the third item.</div></li>
  <li>Fourth item <div>Here is the description of the fourth item.</div></li>
  <li>Fifth item <div>Here is the description of the fifth item.</div></li>
  <li>Sixth item <div>Here is the description of the sixth item.</div></li>
  <li>Seventh item <div>Here is the description of the seventh item.</div></li>
  <li>Eighth item <div>Here is the description of the eighth item.</div></li>
  <li>Ninth item <div>Here is the description of the ninth item.</div></li>
  <li>Tenth item <div>Here is the description of the tenth item.</div></li>
  <li>Eleventh item <div>Here is the description of the eleventh item.</div></li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li div').hide();

  $('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

None of [the column methods I've tried](http://codepen.io/collection/AkNrRN/) get me the exact behavior I want when the elements are resized.

[With CSS columns](http://codepen.io/75th/pen/eNaGvw), expanding/contracting an element makes the items shift unattractively as they're pushed to/pulled from the second column.

[With floated items](http://codepen.io/75th/pen/WvBZRK), the shift is less janky, but they're ordered in a confusing way.

[With flexbox](http://codepen.io/75th/pen/YXbrGp), I can get some pretty good behavior going, but the items go across-then-down — not really columns at all.

I've tried some things with `flex-direction: column`, but I'm new to flexbox, and it's unclear to me how I can get multiple columns without specifying a fixed height on the flex container.

Is there a good way to get balanced columns in HTML/CSS/JS that are stable when child elements change size?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best option I've found is to use JavaScript to [forcibly set the `order` CSS property](http://codepen.io/75th/pen/XbweZJ) to simulate columns with the above horizontal flexbox version:

```
var reorderCourses = function($items, numCols) {
    var count = $items.length;
    var numPerCol = Math.ceil(count / numCols);
    var columns = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        columns[i] = $items.slice(i * numPerCol, (i + 1) * numPerCol);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        columns[i].each(function(index) {
            $(this).css('order', (index * numCols) + i);
        });
    }
};
```